How can I transfer dataframe columns into dataframe rows? (An Elegant Solution)
I have the following data
ticker  company sector  industryGroup   industry    subindustry currency    1999-07-31  1999-10-31  2000-01-31  ...
CompA   Health  Health  Health      Health      Health      USD     12.3        23.33       33.1        ...
CompB   Machine Machine Machine     Machine     Machine     USD     32.1        34.44       23.1        ...                                                             
CompC   Machine Machine Machine     Machine     Machine     USD     32.1        34.44       23.1        ...
CompD   Machine Machine Machine     Machine     Machine     USD     32.1        34.44       23.1        ...

The above is just a sample of the data that is in excel file. The prices go till 02-01-2024 and there are more company row 541 companies to be exact. I wrote a code that takes the columns starting from the first date and puts them in a dataframe with the date column title. Next I took the second column prices and put them in a column with ticker symbol name. The output should be the same as below.
Date        CompA    CompB    CompC    CompD
1999-07-31  12.3     32.1     32.1     32.1
1999-10-31  23.33    34.44    34.44    34.44
2000-01-31  33.1     34.44    34.44    34.44

The is my code:
import pandas as pd


bvmf = pd.read_excel('Market.xlsx')

df = pd.DataFrame()
df['Date'] = bvmf.iloc[0:1, 10:].columns

for i in range(len(bvmf)):
    ticker = bvmf['ticker'][i]
    df[ticker] = bvmf.iloc[i:i+1, 10:].values[0]

There are alot of values. My question, is there a better way to implement this code?

If you have working code that you want to have peer-reviewed for improvement, you should be asking on [codereview.se], which was created specifically for that purpose. This site is designed more for questions about code you're having actual problems with instead. You'll find your experiences here will be much better if you take the time to complete the [tour] and read the [help] pages to learn how the site works.

Re-created your dataframe:
import pandas as pd
columns = ['ticker', 'company', 'sector', 'industryGroup', 'industry', 'subindustry', 'currency', '1999-07-31', '1999-10-31', '2000-01-31']
data = [["CompA","Health","Health","Health","Health","Health","USD",     12.3,23.33,33.1],
        ["CompB","Machine","Machine","Machine","Machine","Machine","USD",32.1,34.44,23.1],
        ["CompC","Machine","Machine","Machine","Machine","Machine","USD",32.1,34.44,23.1],
        ["CompD","Machine","Machine","Machine","Machine","Machine","USD",32.1,34.44,23.1]]

df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=columns)

The following code concatenates "ticker" + "all the dates" and then transposes it.
df2 = pd.concat([df.ticker,df.loc[:, pd.to_datetime(df.columns, errors='coerce', format='mixed').notna()]], axis=1).T

OR without concat:
df2 = df.loc[:,pd.to_datetime(df.columns, errors='coerce', format='mixed').notna() | (df.columns == 'ticker')].T

Note to find all dates in the column I've used answer from the following question: Find all columns with "dateformat" in dataframe.
Output 1:



0
1
2
3




CompA
CompB
CompC
CompD


12.3
32.1
32.1
32.1


23.33
34.44
34.44
34.44


33.1
23.1
23.1
23.1



If you want to replace header with the top row then use the following code:
df2, df2.columns = df2[1:] , df2.iloc[0]

Output 2:



CompA
CompB
CompC
CompD




12.3
32.1
32.1
32.1


23.33
34.44
34.44
34.44


33.1
23.1
23.1
23.1



